# Why is one variable showing up with NA's in my quasipoisson glm?

Tags: r, na, glm

I have carried out a quasipoisson GLM on my data and simplified my model however when I view the summary I can see that one of my variables (Month) is coming up with NA's. This variable is a character however so are some of my other variables and this hasn't caused any issues.

Does anyone know why this variable might be coming up as NA and how to fix it?

Dataset

| Date | DOY | Month | Species | Quantity | Flower selection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Lucorum | 13 | Lavendula |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Lapidarius | 1 | Verbena |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Terrestris | 3 | Centaurea |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Pascorum | 1 | Vicia craccu |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Lapidarius | 7 | Phalcelia |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Terrestris | 4 | Lavendula |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Terrestris | 9 | Verbena |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Lapidarius | 1 | Phalcelia |
| 13/07/2020 | 195 | Jul20 | B Lucorum | 3 | Lavendula |

```r
g1 <- glm(Quantity ~ Location + Recorder + Species + Flower.selection + Date + Month,
          family = quasipoisson(), 
          data = BW)

g3<-update(g2,~.-Recorder, family = quasipoisson())

summary(g3)
```

A sample of the results from `summary(g3)`:

```r
MonthSep-20                                       NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonthMar-21                                       NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonthApr-21                                       NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonthMay-21                                       NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonthJun-21                                       NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonthJul-21                                       NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Comment: Most likely there is some multicollinearity in your data, probably because of some imbalance in your data (e.g. there was one month in which you only collected one species - that's so extreme as to be unlikely, but that kind of thing ...).  What are the results of `mm <- model.matrix(~ Location + Recorder + Species + Flower.selection + Date + Month, data = BW); caret::findLinearCombos(mm)` ? (Can you please edit your question to include the output of `summary()`, as text/code ?)

Comment: @BenBolker Hi Ben, Thanks for your help. I have included the results of summary (g3) in my original post for you and will post the results of mm below for you.

Comment: MonthOct-22       MonthMar-23       MonthApr-23       MonthMay-23           
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.00000     
 1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.00000    
 Median :0.00000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.00000    
 Mean   :0.02101   Mean   :0.01891   Mean   :0.02101   Mean   :0.02101    
 3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.00000    
 Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.00000

Comment: sorry, I wasn't specific enough. (1) I wanted the output of `summary(BW)` (i.e., your data,not the fitted model); (2) I would like to see the results of `caret::findLinearCombos(mm)`, not `mm` itself

Comment: Date          DOY            Month      Start.time       
17/07/2023: 49   Min.   : 75.0   Jul-23 : 49   Length:476                                      
10/08/2021: 46   1st Qu.:154.0   Jul-20 : 46   Class :character  
13/06/2022: 37   Median :198.0   Aug-21 : 46   Mode  :character  
03/06/2021: 30   Mean   :189.2   Jun-22 : 37                                                   
 02/09/2021: 28   3rd Qu.:222.0   Jun-21 : 30                     
 09/08/2022: 25   Max.   :283.0   Sep-21 : 28                     
  (Other)   :261                   (Other):240

Comment: Thanks.  See my answer: I realize in hindsight I didn't need to make you go to all that effort - the problem was clear in the structure of the data you posted, it just didn't click at first.

Comment: Hi Ben, when I try to run caret::findlinearCombos(mm) it says that there is no package called caret

Comment: (1) you would need to `install.packages("caret")` (2) You don't need to do that any more, see my answer below ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` and `Month` are redundant predictors in your model: once you know the date, the month is fully specified (so adding the month to your model won't add any information). Redundant/collinear parameters mess up the linear algebra that is used internally to do the computations, so they are omitted/assigned `NA` values.

You could leave out one or the other (if both are factors, then dropping month won't affect the model at all), or use a mixed model with month and date as random effects grouping variables (date nested within month) [although depending on the package you use, `family = "quasipoisson"` may not be available: see the [relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fitting-models-with-overdispersion) for alternatives]